# Multiple return in VB select case

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am writing C# codes converted from some legacy VB codes. The VB codes from one of the functions are:

```
Private Function function1() As Double

        Dim variable2 As Double = 0

        If variable1 = 6 Then
            Select Case variable3
                Case Is <= 1500 : Return Constant1
                Case Is <= 2000 : Return Constant2
                Case Is <= 2500 : Return Constant3
                Case Is <= 3000 : Return Constant4
                Case Else : Return Constant5
            End Select
            variable2 = variable2 +3
        End If
        Return variable2
End Function
```

Variable 1, variable 3 and all the constants are class-level fields.
It seems the return value are from variable 2 after it was processed inside the If statement.

Could anyone advise why there are multiple return clause in the select case statement? My guess is it assigns constant values to variable3 for future processes, anyone agree with me?

Comment: It will only return one value, not all of them.  If the value of `variable3` is <= 1500 it will return Constant1, if it's greater than 1500 and less than or equal to 2000, it will return Constant2, etc.

Comment: Your code will not compile. `Case Else : Constant5` is invalid. Can you show us the actual code, please? Even if it *did* compile (and was `return Constant5`) - it means the parts regarding `variable2` will never be executed.

Comment: Hi, your are right, should be return Constant5, I amended it.

Answer (score 2):

Select Case is simply the VB.NET equivalent of C#'s switch ... case

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Any value you return within a case will return from function1 itself.

If there is a return in all cases, then the statement:

```
variable2 = variable2 +3
```

...is unreachable and...

```
Return variable2
```

will always return 0.

Comment: Thanks mate! I think that is the bug in the legacy codes.

Comment: @DennisL If this answer (or the other) solved your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there are any multiple return variables. There may be a bug where your code is assigning

> variable2 = variable2 +3  //This line will never executed.

To execute this line you need assign the constant value into variable2 instead of returning from each case.

Lastly if variable1 is not equal to 6 then this function will always return 0.